# Sorting strings with accented characters in python

Tags: python, sorting, collation, diacritics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python not sorting unicode properly. Strcoll doesn't help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412933/python-not-sorting-unicode-properly-strcoll-doesnt-help)

I'm trying to sort some words in alphabetical order. Here is how I do it:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import locale

# Make sure the locale is in french
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "fr_FR.UTF-8")
print "locale: " + str(locale.getlocale())

# The words are in alphabetical order
words = ["liche", "lichée", "lichen", "lichénoïde", "licher", "lichoter"]

for word in sorted(words, cmp=locale.strcoll):
    print word.decode("string-escape")
```

I'm expecting that the words are printed in the same order as they are defined, but here is what I get:

```
locale: ('fr_FR', 'UTF8')
liche
lichen
licher
lichoter
lichée
lichénoïde
```

The **é** character is treated as if it's greater than **z**.

It seems I'm misunderstanding how `locale.strcoll` is comparing strings. What comparator function should I use to get the words sorted alphabetically?

Comment: It looks like it works correctly. I cannot see "z".

Comment: There is no `z` in this example, but the `é` comes after the `o`, which is not alphabetical order.

Comment: And I've also confirmed that it works fine in 2.7 here. Something not-Python is wrong.

Comment: I just tried with python 2.6.1 (which is the default Snow Leopard installation) and it does not sort as expected.

Comment: Then the problem is with how Python interacts with OS X, not with Python itself.

Comment: Implementation of strcoll in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/locale.py` is simply `return cmp(a,b)` What is yours?

Comment: @0xced: That's a fallback if it can't import `_locale` (which will be compiled code), at least on my Linux system.

Comment: Indeed, it's also a fallback on Mac OS X. So now I have no idea why strcoll does not work properly then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally chose to [strip diacritics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string/518232#518232) and compare the stripped version of the strings so that I don't have to add the PyICU dependency.