# Why it shows True if I type print('a'>'A')?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
print('a'>'A')
```

> why it shows "True" result what is the logic??

Comment: Please don't spam multiple python tags, point only the one you're using.

Comment: ASCII for 'a' is 97 and for 'A' is 65

Answer (score 2):

Look up the ordinals for these characters -- the position in the ASCII or Unicode table for each character or code point:

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> ord('A')
65
>>> print('a'>'A')
True
```

97 is greater than 65. Thus, `a` comes after `A`.

See [Sort dictionary by key using locale/collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203550/sort-dictionary-by-key-using-locale-collation) for discussion of how comparison can be done according to locale-specific collation order instead.

Comment: It's worth noting that that's the [ASCII value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) of those particular characters.

Comment: Yeah, didn't see the edit on time. In any case, +1 from me because this is the correct answer.