# Does Python 3 string ordering depend on locale?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

Do Python's `str.__lt__` or `sorted` order characters based on their unicode index or by some locale-dependent collation rules?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String Comparison Technique Used by Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806911/string-comparison-technique-used-by-python)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, the question you linked seems to be more about the principle of lexicographic ordering.

Comment: no, it's same question you asked (does "<" performs culture aware comparison?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, string ordering does not take locale into account. It is based entirely on the Unicode codepoint sort order.

The `locale` module does provide you with a [`locale.strxform()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.strxfrm) that can be used for locale-specific sorting:

```
import locale

sorted(list_of_strings, key=locale.strxfrm)
```

This tool *is* quite limited; for any serious collation task you probably want to use the [PyICU library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU):

```
import PyICU

collator = PyICU.Collator.createInstance(PyICU.Locale(locale_spec))
sorted(list_of_strings, key=collator.getSortKey)
```

Comment: [it may fail](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3412933/4279), [PyICU could be used instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16701346/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: agreed; added a reference.