# How to sort a list with an exception in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort a dictionary alphabetically but we have other letters in Turkish because of that i can't use sorted() function.

For example we have letter "ç" which comes after letter "c". How can i make letter "ç" comes after letter "c"?

Btw it will not be just 1 letter we have plenty more and dictionary will contain hundereds of words and values.

Comment: You can provide a key function that maps letters to e.g. an ordinal position in the alphabet.

Comment: So do you have al alphabet? That is a list of all the letters you need?

Comment: Related: [Does Python 3 string ordering depend on locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26505661/4518341), [How do I sort unicode strings alphabetically in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1097908/4518341), [Python not sorting unicode properly. Strcoll doesn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3412933/4518341). Also related to Turkey and internationalization: [What is The Turkey Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/796986/4518341)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple solution based on the Turkish alphabet:

```
alphabet = "abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprsştuüvyz"
words = ["merhaba", "aşk", "köpek", "Teşekkürle"]

sorted_words = sorted(words, key=lambda word: tuple(alphabet.index(c) for c in word.lower()))
```

This code is able to sort words using the lexicographic order. It also works with words containing capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `key` argument for `sorted`, however the main challenge is how to define which letter is "bigger". Maybe you can use some table of letters' values to sort them. Like this:

```
LETTER_VALUES = {
    ...
    "c": 100,
    "ç": 110
    ...
    }

sorted_ar = sorted(char_array, key=lambda ch: LETTER_VALUES.get(ch1, ord(ch)))
```

Of course, numbers are just random for example and `ord` the simplest example for "failure default".

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by injecting your own alphabet order, example:

```
letters = "abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprsştuüvyz"
letters_dict = {i:letters.index(i) for i in letters}
print(sorted("açobzöğge", key=letters_dict.get))
```

The above should output:
`['a', 'b', 'ç', 'e', 'g', 'ğ', 'o', 'ö', 'z']`

Comment: This does not work with capital letters. Also this only order letters, not words!