# Where/How can I obtain a locale's alphabet in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, locale, alphabetical

Is there a Python library, or online resource I can use to programmatically obtain the alphabet of a particular locale?

For example, for the 'es_ES' locale I'd like to obtain `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz'` or similar.

Comment: there is no standard list for each locales.

Comment: if you need to sort alphabetically according to a locale; you could [use PyICU](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16701346/4279). Here's [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11124645/4279)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't actually an answer to this question yet, so I though I would add one for future reference.

The Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR) contains exemplar data for most defined locales available in CLDR. Exemplar data incluses the main/standard exemplars, i.e all the characters needed to write the language. Auxiliary exemplars are additional characters that may be needed for loan words for instance. Auxiliary characters aren't part fo the alphabet, and not normally used. Exemplar data also includes Index character and punctuation. What is available will vary across locales, but as a minimum the main/standard exemplars will be available.

ICU4C, via PyICU, provides access to this data, via the `icu.LocaleData` class.

```py
import icu

# Create a LocaleData instance for the es_ES locale.
ld = icu.LocaleData("es_ES")
# Create a collator instance using an es_ES locale instance.
collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale('es_ES'))

# Create a Uuicode Set of standard (main) exemplar characters,
# including case mappings.
exemplars = ld.getExemplarSet(
    icu.USET_ADD_CASE_MAPPINGS,    
    icu.ULocaleDataExemplarSetType.ES_STANDARD)

# It is possible to use numeric values of the above 
#  * icu.USET_ADD_CASE_MAPPINGS = 4
#  * icu.ULocaleDataExemplarSetType.ES_STANDARD = 0
# exemplars = ld.getExemplarSet(4, 0)

# type cast to a list.
alphabet = list(exemplars)

# Sort list using Spanish collation.
alphabet.sort(key=collator.getSortKey)

print(alphabet)
# ['a', 'A', 'á', 'Á', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'e', 'E',
# 'é', 'É', 'f', 'F', 'g', 'G', 'h', 'H', 'i', 'I', 'í', 'Í',
# 'j', 'J', 'k', 'K', 'l', 'L', 'm', 'M', 'n', 'N', 'ñ', 'Ñ',
# 'o', 'O', 'ó', 'Ó', 'p', 'P', 'q', 'Q', 'r', 'R', 's', 'S',
# 't', 'T', 'u', 'U', 'ú', 'Ú', 'ü', 'Ü', 'v', 'V', 'w', 'W',
# 'x', 'X', 'y', 'Y', 'z', 'Z']
```

If there is no available data for the locale you require, it is worth checking [SLDR](https://github.com/silnrsi/sldr). The files are XML files and will need to be parsed for the required data. Data can also be read from the CDLR repository on GitHub.

```py
import icu
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib.request import urlopen
# url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/silnrsi/sldr/master/sldr/d/daa.xml"
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unicode-org/cldr/main/common/main/es.xml"
response = urlopen(url).read()
tree = ET.fromstring(response)
result = tree.findall('characters/exemplarCharacters')[0]

collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale('es_ES'))
exemplars = icu.UnicodeSet(result.text)
alphabet = list(exemplars)
alphabet.extend([c.upper() for c in alphabet])
alphabet.sort(key=collator.getSortKey)
print(alphabet)
# ['a', 'A', 'á', 'Á', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'e', 'E', 'é', 'É', 'f', 'F', 'g', 'G', 'h', 'H', 'i', 'I', 'í', 'Í', 'j', 'J', 'k', 'K', 'l', 'L', 'm', 'M', 'n', 'N', 'ñ', 'Ñ', 'o', 'O', 'ó', 'Ó', 'p', 'P', 'q', 'Q', 'r', 'R', 's', 'S', 't', 'T', 'u', 'U', 'ú', 'Ú', 'ü', 'Ü', 'v', 'V', 'w', 'W', 'x', 'X', 'y', 'Y', 'z', 'Z']
```

For a version that doesn't use PyICU, it is necessary to add processing to convert the set syntax into a list. Digraphs and base character with combining diacritics are within braces, spaces are only used between primary weight collation elements, no spaces between secondary weight collation elements:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib.request import urlopen
import regex
import locale

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unicode-org/cldr/main/common/main/es.xml"
response = urlopen(url).read()
tree = ET.fromstring(response)
result = tree.findall('characters/exemplarCharacters')[0]

def exemplars_to_list(e:str)->list[str]:
    e = e[1:-1].replace(" ", "")
    l = regex.findall(r'{[\p{alpha}\p{Mn}]+}|\X', e)
    l = [s[1:-1] if '{' in s else s for s in l]
    return l

alphabet = exemplars_to_list(result.text)
alphabet.extend([c.upper() for c in alphabet])

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE, 'es_ES.UTF-8')
alphabet.sort(key=locale.strxfrm)
print(alphabet)
# ['A', 'Á', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'É', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'Í', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'Ñ', 'O', 'Ó', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'Ú', 'Ü', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'á', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'é', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'í', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ñ', 'o', 'ó', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'ú', 'ü', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

**UPDATE:**

For some languages, the main exemplars are the alphabet, for other languages additional letters beyond the alphabet are required for writing teh language. For Instance some languages need to mark tone, but tones aren't included in alphabet.

For some languages the index characters are the same as the alphabet.

It is best to review the XML files for your target language to determine if you need the exemplar characters or the index characters. Refer to

1. [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/tree/main/common/main) (CLDR)
2. [SIL Locale Data repository](https://github.com/silnrsi/sldr/tree/master/sldr) (SLDR)

For completeness sake, I'll include a modification of the above code, that will get the index characters for a locale:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib.request import urlopen
import regex
import locale

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unicode-org/cldr/main/common/main/es.xml"
response = urlopen(url).read()
tree = ET.fromstring(response)
result = tree.find('characters/exemplarCharacters[@type="index"]')

def exemplars_to_list(e:str)->list[str]:
    e = e[1:-1].replace(" ", "")
    l = regex.findall(r'{[\p{alpha}\p{Mn}]+}|\X', e)
    l = [s[1:-1] if '{' in s else s for s in l]
    return l

alphabet = []
if len(result.text) != 0:
    alphabet = exemplars_to_list(result.text)
    # alphabet.extend([c.lower() for c in alphabet])
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_COLLATE, 'es_ES.UTF-8')
    alphabet.sort(key=locale.strxfrm)
    print(alphabet)
    # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'Ñ', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is what I'm looking for: https://github.com/CrossWaterBridge/python-indexed-collation/, although I'm interested in knowing if there's a standard out there for Python.